# Laravel and Thujohn's Twitter Package

Tags: php, twitter, laravel

I have just implemented thujohn's Twitter API Package for Laravel (https://github.com/thujohn/twitter-l4). I was able to set it up and I also included the API credentials.

When I go to the home view to view the tweets, I always get

```
stdClass Object ( [errors] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [message] => Bad           Authentication data [code] => 215 ) ) )
```

(I am printing out the data for debugging)

I have tried other methods than trying to get the users timeline, but they all return the same thing.

I have made a helper class to help with the behind the scenes work for the retrieval of data. I have set this up with Laravel and made a class folder.

Here is the Helper Class:

```
class Helpers {
    public static function twitterFeed($screen_name='mackhankins', $count='3', $include_retweets='false', $exclude_replies='true')
    {
        $twitterfeed = Cache::remember('twitterfeed', 30, function() use ($screen_name, $count, $include_retweets, $exclude_replies) {
            return Twitter::getUserTimeline(array('screen_name' => $screen_name, 'count' => $count, 'include_rts' => $include_retweets, 'exclude_replies' => $exclude_replies));
        });
        if(!empty($twitterfeed))
        {
            return $twitterfeed;
        }
        else
        {
            return array();
        }
    }
}
```

The HomeController:

```
class HomeController extends BaseController {

    public function __construct()
    {
        /*Get Tweets*/
        View::share('tweets', Helpers::twitterFeed('tjyouschak', '10', false, true));
    }

    public function getHome()
    {
        return View::make('home');
    }
}
```

The View:

```
{{ print_r($tweets) }}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: did you solve problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Code 215 is Bad Authentication data. You need to auth first, then get tweets

https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/response-codes

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets